# Insert a linearLayout inside another linearLayout

Tags: android, view, tags, addition, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to insert a `LinearLayout` inside another `LinearLayout`. I don't know if what I am doing is right or not. **I need to try it this way, without using inflation**.

```java
      LinearLayout address2;
      address2 = new LinearLayout(this);
      address2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sfsp2_layout);

      LinearLayout teste3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.se_contentAdressPostal);

      LinearLayout teste4 = (LinearLayout)teste3.findViewWithTag("teste");
      teste4.addView(address2);
```

---

**LinearLayout teste3**

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/se_contentAdressPostal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_tile_address_postal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/socio_form_structured_postal" />
```

---

**LinearLayout teste4**

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sfsp_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_tile"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="teste" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sfsp_layout_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tile"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:tag="teste" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sfsp_btStructuredPostal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:hint="@string/sfsp_btStructuredPostal" /> .......
```

---

**LinearLayour address2 ( The layout that i need to insert in layout4)**

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sfsp2_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_tile"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sfsp2_etStructuredPostalApartado"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.14"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/sfsp2_etStructuredPostalApartado"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false" >
```

The `LinearLayout` "teste4" is inside "teste3". I need to insert `LinearLayout` "address2" inside "teste4". Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?.

Comment: Is the `<include...` part in your layout xml file?  Also, you only need `xmlns:android="..."` bit only in the first XML element in each file; you can (and probably should) delete it from others.

Comment: Also, are all these layouts in the same file?

Comment: Hi ikh. Thanks for reply.The layouts are all from diferent files :)

Comment: The include part include the teste4 inside teste3. Now i need to insert address2 inside teste4 by click a button without inflation.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use view inflation?  If you're trying to load a view from another XML file, you'd have to inflate the XML file first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some misunderstanding here about how the `findViewById` works.  I'll try to explain it below.  Hope this helps, let me know if it doesn't.

There are two possible `findViewById()` that can be used.

1. [`Activity.findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29): this can be used to find a view in the current activity's main content view --  that is, the view that was set using [`setContentView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29).  It cannot be used for any other purpose.  For example, it cannot find a view from any other layout file -- the function simply would have no way of knowing how to find it.  As far as I can tell, this is the function you're trying to use.  If the last XML file you have is not the main layout, then the line `address2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.sfsp2_layout)` will fail.
2. [`View.findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29):  this function can be used to find a view that is contained in some other view.  E.g. if you have `view1` that contains `view2`, and `view2` has ID `some_id`, then you can find `view2` by calling `view1.findViewById(R.id.some_id)`.  In order for this to work, `view1` has to be fully initialized.  E.g. if `view1`'s description is in XML, it has to be fully inflated first.

In essence, if you want to work with a view that is described in a separate XML file, you have to inflate it first.  I don't think there is a way around it.